# if i assign pointer 1 to be equal to pointer 2 and then change pointer 2 does pointer 1 change?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

I've written the follwing function:

```
int read_words(char* words[], int size, int max_str_len)
{
    char* pointers = (char*)malloc(max_str_len * sizeof(char) +1);  // the + 1 is for the null 
terminator

    if(pointers==NULL)
    {
         free(pointers);
         return -1;
    }

    int i=0;
    int j=1;

    while((i<size ) && (scanf("%c", & *pointers) != EOF ))
    {


        while(scanf("%c", & *(pointers + j)) != ' ' && j<max_str_len)
        {
            j++;
        }
        *(pointers + j) ='\0';

        words[i] = pointers;
        j=0;
        i++;
    }
    free(pointers);
    return i;
```

}

which is supposed to read a bunch of strings (which is in C language defined as an array of chars) and assign them pointers from the array words. (the strings' max length is max_str_len)

then i tried using it in the following loop:

```
while(i<num_words)
{
    while(*(words[i]+j) != '\0')
    {
        *(words[i]+j) = encrypt(key, *(words[i]+j));
        j++;
    }
    j=0;

    i++;
}
```

where encrypt gets a key array and encrypts each char it gets based on the array.

For some reason the program gets terminated after recieving the input for the array words (so I think the problem is in the function read_words, I'm not sure the function is actually scanning the words.

note: others who tried helping me with the function said that I should scan the words as whole not as individual chars but the function's time complexity is supposed to be O(size*max_str_len) and if I don't scan them as chars it won't meet the conditions.

to be honest I'm not sure how to use malloc, I can't seem to find the mistakes of the code.
I also have a general question about malloc:
If p is a dynamic allocation of a certain bytes size, and arr is an array of pointers: 
If p is pointing at a specific variable and we define arr[0] to be equal to p, then we change p to be a different variable, does arr[0] still point to the first variable? Or is its value lost and now arr[0] isn’t pointing at anything or pointing at the new variable?

Meaning in the function above:
If I define p to be:
`char* p = (char*)malloc(max_atr_len*sizeof(char));`

And then I scan the words as following: 
`scanf(“%s”, & p);`

And then I write: 
`words[i] = p;`

If I then scan a different word, is the value of the first word lost or does words[i] still point at it?

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: If it was two `int` variables, would you have the same question? Each variable is separate and distinct. Assigning to, or modifying, one variable doesn't affect any other variable. That the variables are pointers doesn't change that fact.

Comment: However, if you *dereference* a pointer, to change what it points to, then that's different because then you're not modifying the pointer variable itself.

Comment: There's a lot of problems with this code. Overall, try to _keep it simple_. For example use array access notation `a[i]` rather than hard to read pointer arithmetic `*(a+i)`. And why are you using malloc in the first place? Unless the strings you expect are huge, you could just allocate a local array on the stack instead.

Comment: `scanf("%s", & p)` should be `scanf("%s", p)`

Comment: Start with `for(int i=0; i<size; i++) { scanf("%s", words[i]); }` which is essentially what all this complex code does in practice. Then when you have that working, modify the code from there, add error handling etc.

Comment: `while(scanf("%c", & *(pointers + j)) != ' ' &&` The first part of this condition will always be true because you will never convert 32 values when you only pass 1 format specifier. You should read manpage for `scanf` again to see what it returns. You should also be aware that this instruction reads into same position as the `scanf` in the `while` condition a few lines above for `j==0` which overrides the first character.

Answer (score 0):

After assignment both pointers point to the same data object, but you are free to change each pointer to point somewhere else without affecting the other pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", p);` doesn't change `p`. It changes that to which `p` points.

`words[0] = p;` only copies the value of `p` (the address), nothing more.

---

Let's consider the following snippet:

```c
char* p = malloc(...);
scanf("%s", p);
words[0] = p;
scanf("%s", p);
words[1] = p;
```

`p` is only changed by the first line, so `p`, `words[0]` and `words[1]` all have the same value: the address of the memory block you allocated.

The only memory block was populated by the first call to `scanf`, and overwritten by the second call to `scanf`.

```
words                malloc'ed block
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--...
|        --------+-->| I | n | p | u | t | 2 | ␀ |
+----------+     |   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--...
|        --------+
+----------+     |
                 |
                 |
p                |
+----------+     |
|        --------+
+----------+
```

---

Now let's consider the following snippet:

```c
char* p = malloc(...);
scanf("%s", p);
words[0] = p;
p = malloc(...);
scanf("%s", p);
words[1] = p;
```

- The value of `words[0]` is the address of the first memory block you allocated.
- The value of `words[1]` is the address of the second memory first block you allocated.

and

- The first memory block you allocated was populated by the first call to `scanf`.
- The second memory block you allocated was populated by the second call to `scanf`.

```
words                First malloc'ed block
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--...
|        ----------->| I | n | p | u | t | 1 | ␀ |
+----------+         +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--...
|        --------+
+----------+     |   Second malloc'ed block
                 |   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--...
                 +-->| I | n | p | u | t | 2 | ␀ |
p                |   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--...
+----------+     |
|        --------+
+----------+
```

---

By the way, note that your use of `scanf` is unsafe. [Bad things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) will happen if the input is larger than you anticipate.